# Espacenet - date when online records begin

Tags: espacenet

What date does Espacenet hold patent data from? Is it still 1890?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Espacenet contains many patents listings, you can get patents starting from 1790s more comprehensive coverage list can be seen in following resource provided by EPO

http://www.epo.org/searching/data/data/patent-additions.html

Answer (score 0):

Escpacenet's archives are the result of merging the EPO's database and the INPADOC database (holded by WIPO in Vienna). For more information take a look at this blog (not really active lately, but it's a good source).
http://www.intellogist.com/wiki/INPADOC
After 1980, the collection is quite comprehensive. Before that, judging from my searches, it is focused on US patents and european countries like Netherlands, France, Germany, UK. And some Japanese.